# Clone copy of custom class

Tags: java, oop

I have a Board class that has the following private variables:

```
private int[][] table = new int[BOARD_DIMENSION][BOARD_DIMENSION] 
private List<Character> movesTaken = new ArrayList<Character>();
private List<Integer> future = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I want to be able to clone a new Board via the following method:

```
public Board copy(Board parent){
    return new Board(parent);
}



public Board(Board parent){
    System.arraycopy(parent.getTable(),0,this.table,0,parent.getTable().length);
    this.future = parent.getFuture();
    this.initialiseTileReps();
    this.initialiseValueReps();
    this.movesTaken = parent.getMovesTaken();
}
```

However when I copy a Board object:
    `Board U = root.copy(root);` (where root is the board I want to copy).

If I modify U `U.move('U');`

I expect that to modify U's table that contains all the game pieces.

However it also modifies root's table.

Can someone please help me clone my custom Board?

Comment: `System.arrayCopy()` only performs a shallow copy of the array elements. You'll need to manually iterate over the array and `System.arrayCopy()` each inner array (for this situation, at least, because a "shallow" copy of the elements in a primitive array would function just like a deep copy)

Comment: Why you don't override `clone()` method?

Comment: @Masud Generally alternatives such as static factories or copy constructors are preferred to `clone()`, as `clone()` as is could (and should) be considered broken. Joshua Bloch has an item in *Effective Java* that explains things a lot better than I could. I could still try to summarize if you don't have access to the book.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you are in `OOP` and array copy copies references not "clones" actual objects. You would have to manually copy objects in your array.

Little bit messy, but 100% functional method for "cloning" objects woulkd be to serialize it, and then deserialize using eg. `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectIntputStream`. This would create deep copy of targeted object. It is possible as far, as every component of your class can be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
public Board copy(Board parent){
    return new Board(parent);
}



public Board(Board parent){
    System.arraycopy(parent.getTable(),0,this.table,0,parent.getTable().length);
    this.future = new ArrayList<Character>(parent.getFuture());
    this.initialiseTileReps();
    this.initialiseValueReps();
    this.movesTaken = new ArrayList<Character>(parent.getMovesTaken());
}
```

Comment: I would explain what changes you made and why. Also, your code isn't completely correct. `System.arrayCopy()` only performs a shallow copy, so the inner arrays are still duplicated. In addition, there is no real reason to provide a static factory when you have a publicly accessible copy constructor.